# Running web-component-tester on TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, web-component-tester, wct

Can someone help me running `wct` on teamcity. I have the buld configured, but I get below error when running `wct`:

```
[12:15:54][Step 1/1] /opt/jetbrains/TeamCityAgent/work/f73ec8c1325df542/node_modules/web-component-tester/bin/wct:21
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     promise.then(() => process.exit(0), () => process.exit(1));
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]                   ^
[12:15:54][Step 1/1] SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     at startup (node.js:129:16)
[12:15:54][Step 1/1]     at node.js:814:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Running wct via npm script removes the error.